# Web app to extract all colours of an image

Tags: gratis, web-apps, images, color

Does a web-app exist where I can upload an image, and all the colours used in that image are analyzed and displayed for me to use, with a sample next to the colour?

Requirements:

- free
- web-app
- upload .jpg, .png (anything else is a bonus)
- shows me the HTML HEX code, and RGB code
- shows me the name (if applicable)
- shows me a sample of the colour for every colour code.

Comment: Which resolutions must it support? A client-side app with JS would surely be possible, but probably only up to a certain resolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Counteracting my rusty HTML 5/JS skills, I've created such a webapp:

Website: http://comfreek.github.io/ColorSplitter/
Repository: http://github.com/ComFreek/ColorSplitter

It is/does:

- free (MIT license)
- a webapp (the image is processed on the client side in the browser, so no image is ever uploaded to a server)
- support JPG and PNG files among others
  The webapp can handle every format the  browser supports loading into an `<img>` element)
- show the HEX and RGBA color codes
- show the CSS color name if applicable
- show a color sample in a box for every found color

These browsers are known to work with ColorSplliter:

- Google Chrome 39.0.2171.93 (on Android)
- Google Chrome 41.0.2258.2 canary (on Windows)
- Opera 26.0.1656.60
- Firefox Nightly 37.0a1 (2014-12-25)
     (Note that the number of pages and the current page number are erroneously not shown, however,
  the rest of the web app is still usable.)

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of ColorSplitter fed with the Google logo]

Comment: I'm wondering what sort of application something like this would have.